# Failing to catch a specific error

Tags: python, import

I wrote this simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 -tt

import subprocess

def main()
  try:
    process = subprocess.check_output(['unvalidcommand'],shell=True)
  except CalledProcessError:
    print 'there is the calledProcessError'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Expected output: `there is the calledProcessError`

What I got: `NameError: global name 'CalledProcessError' is not defined`

Comment: Should be `subprocess.CalledProcessError`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def main():
  try:
    process = subprocess.check_output(['unvalidcommand'],shell=True)
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError: # need to use subprocess.CalledProcessError
    print 'there is the calledProcessError'
main()
there is the calledProcessError
/bin/sh: 1: unvalidcommand: not found
```

Or just import what you need from `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import check_output,CalledProcessError

def main():
  try:
    process = check_output(['unvalidcommand'],shell=True)
  except CalledProcessError:
    print 'there is the calledProcessError'
main()
```

Answer (score 5):

[`subprocess.CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) is not a builtin exception. You need to qualify the exception name to use it.

```
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or you need to  import it explicitly:

```
from subprocess import CalledProcessError
```